# Material-UI DataGrid column names getting truncated

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

My column names keep getting truncated, but they should fit in the space.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use [`text-overflow: clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) to remove the ellipsis if you don't want it:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "& .MuiDataGrid-cell, & .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitle": {
      textOverflow: "clip"
    }
  }
});
```

```
<DataGrid className={classes.root}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: These are the column headers, how do I remove the ellipsis from the headers?  I've tried columnHeader ,columnHeaderTitle ,columnHeaderTitleContainer to no avail/

Comment: @ecruncher you can inspect the elements to get the class name of the grid header, I've updated the answer for you.

Comment: Thank you @NearHuscarl, unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be overriding the textOverflow in the browser elements

Comment: @ecruncher can you put your code on Codesandbox? It works fine in mine.